# Retracting a flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, flagging

Is there any way to retract a flag that has been cast accidentally and the post has not undergone any change after the flagging?

I saw this post on [Retracting flags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10703/retracting-flags) and that the feature request was supported. What consequence did it have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes, you can now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#281010), both for questions and for answers: click on "flag" (below the already flagged post) and click on the dark blue button "Retract flag" below the list of flagging reasons.